# Retrieve the traffic variable in RankedReport of Adobe Sitecatalyst

Tags: api, adobe, report, analytics, adobe-analytics

Is it possible to fetch a traffic variable sProp1 along with PageName and Url when issuing a GetReport request of a Ranked report?

Let us say I have the following passed to SiteCatalyst (Omniture) via Java Script.

```
s.pageName = o_title; // Page Name
s.channel = o_structure; // SiteSection
s.prop1 = o_inode // Traffic variable also the Primary Key Id of the PageName
```

Now, if I run a RankedReport, I will get the following

PageName
PageViews
Url

Along with this info, I will also be interested in fetching the s.prop1 value. I will need the s.prop1 value to use it on my db to query the first sentence of the article from db (and other metadata) and show the results on the results page that shows the most popular pages. Can this be achieved? I mean is it possible to get the traffic variable associated with the pageName?

Thanks,
Rag

Answer (score 0):

OK. I think I if I add another element (prop1) I get the breakdown.        {
    "reportDescription":{
        "reportSuiteID":"*******",
        "dateFrom":"2013-03-06",
        "dateTo":"2013-03-15",
        "metrics":[
            {
                "id":"pageviews",
                "name":"Page Views",
                "type":"number"
            }
        ],
        "sortBy":"pageviews",
        "elements":[
            {
        "id":"siteSection"
            },
            {
        "id":"page"
            },
            {
        "id":"prop1"
            }
        ],
        "locale":"en_US"
    },
    "validate":"false"
}